# Clickable panel with data-toggle modal

Tags: xpages

I have a panel in a Xpage. I want onclick open a modal-dialog.
The modal is insert and hidden. ID = fullmodal.
How can I do that?

```
data-toggle="modal" href="#fullmodal"

<xp:panel
    tagName="a">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="onclick">
            xp:this.value>
                <What should be here?>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get all of your task correctly. But regarding the `onclick` event you should add an `eventHandler` child control, rather than using the panel's `attrs` property. Works just like this:

```
<xp:panel
    id="pnWithEvent">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:requestScope.testEvt="test"}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:panel>
```

*Hint:* as you see the eventHandler control is a child to the panel which in fact is the same what you get for a button control. So: as long as you're not yet familiar with this all I find it easiest to start with creating a button control, do all your programming and testing, and then when you're done just move the button's `<xp:eventHandler>` node into the `<xp:panel>` control, and you're all set.

EDIT:
Instead of using a panel you could also go for a `<xp:div>` control. Advantage here is that this control already is prepared for event handlers (both server- and client-side). You'll find this under "Other... >> Container >> Div" (*Dis*advantage, btw. is that `<xp:div>` cannot be bound to a data source...)

Comment: You're right. If the button is good then I can get the code.
BUT I don't know what I must type in the xp:button. 
My button is now this:
<button
 class="btn"
 data-toggle="modal"
 href="#fullmodal">
 Open
</button>

Comment: Sorry, don't have the slightest idea regarding data-toggle or href. Those aren't standard attributes neither to a button nor to the eventHandler. - Regarding a modal dialog you should have a look at the dialog control (<xe:dialog>) from the Extendion Library control group. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, (<xe:dialog>) is good but not responsive enough for me. I have there the problem that the content is responsive but the dialog not. Now I try the  Bootstrap-modal (http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/). With the button is that okay but not with the panel onclick.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see, and you're right: my <xp:eventHandler> example was meant to trigger a server-side event, whereas obvioulsy you are thinking about client-side triggers. In that case inside the eventHandler it would be <xp:this.script> instead of <xp:this.action>. - I added a second option to my response using <xp:div> instead of a panel...